# Is there a benefit/negative to using a username as a "primary/unique key" in a mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, unique-key, bigdata, database

```
User1 {
  _id: "my_user1",
  name: "john smith",
  email: "blah@test.com,
  friends: [
    "my_user2",
    "my_user3",
    "my_user4",
  ]
}
```

This would be the example.  My site layout is blah.com/user/.  It seems things would be easier by just using the username as the unique key for the database. Does this cause slow downs or would this be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you see people use fixed IDs rather than usernames for a couple of reasons:

- Often, usernames may be changed (say, changing my username from 'bob' to 'robert')
- IDs, especially numeric IDs, can often be stored and indexed more efficiently

Comment: Should I use the built in objectid?

Comment: Mongo gives you the freedom to do *either*. And maybe I'm wrong, but I don't know that it'd be that hard to change between one form or another, at least early on.  Both forms of key have their advantages, but if it's this point that's keeping you from starting to develop your model, I'd say flip a coin or go with your first pick but prepare to deal with the consequences.

Answer (score 2):

Under the premise that usernames don't change often, using the username as a key has its benefits.

When you look at the profile of a user, you certainly want to see a list of their friends. When you store the friends as readable names, you can show this list without an additional database queries. But when you store them as IDs, the name of every single friend needs to be looked up with an additional query, which can take a while.

Comment: One would assume that the friends list would have the automatically generated ids for his friends (as that's the point of automatic ids... they don't change.  If the user kills an old account and gets a new one, the user gets a new id).

Comment: At the same time, of course using the username can have its benefits.  This is just a rehash of the old natural key/automatic key arguments.

Comment: @JayC but this argument doesn't apply to MongoDB in the same way as it applies to relational databases. Because joins in MongoDB are so expensive, you should try to store all relevant data in one collection instead of spreading it over many.

Comment: If the join is expensive, do the rare join action and cache the relevant data in your document or somewhere else so that data retrieval is generally not a join and figure out a caching policy.  The argument still applies.  You still need some data coherency in some aspects of your model.